# what's best way to create a class representing nested xml in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inner-classes

consider the following xml file

```
<Dataset>
    <Table1>
        <colA>AAA</colA>
        <colB>BBB</colB>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <colA>aa</colA>
        <colB>bb</colB>
    </Table1>
    <Table2>
        <colX>xxx</colX>
    </Table1>
</Dataset>
```

What would be the best way to structure a class to hold the records from that file (using the ArrayList of the outer class)?

---

I've tried using inner classes, like this:

```
class Dataset {
    inner class Table1 {
        var colA:String = ""
        var colB:String = ""
    }
    inner class Table2 {
        var colX:String = "x"
    }
}
```

The issue is - when I create an instance of the Dataset class I cannot set the properties of the inner classes within it, even though I can read them (is it because they are not instantiated?)
In other words, the output of the code below is xx rather than xOK

```
val dataset = Dataset()
print("${dataset.Table2().colX}")    //returns x as in the class declaration
dataset.Table2().colX = "OK"
print("${dataset.Table2().colX}")    //returns x, but I want it to return OK
```

I can set the properties when I instantiate the inner classes in the outer class:

```
class Dataset {
    val table1 = Table1()
    val table2 = Table2()
    inner class Table1 {
...
```

but as I mentioned earlier, I append records using ArrayList< Dataset>

which means (if I understand it correctly), that when I create a dataset for a Table1 entry and then append it to the ArrayList, I still have dataset.table2 instantiated in that dataset, even though it's not used

I would also be fine with instantiating the inner classes like this:

```
table1 = Dataset().Table1()
```

as long as I could then add them to the existing Dataset instance

```
val dataset = Dataset()
dataset.Table1() = table1    //this bit doesn't work for me :(
```

---

So to summarize:

1) Any idea on how to better structure the Dataset class?

2) If not, how to set the properties of an inner class within instance of its outer class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definitions for Table1 and Table2 are nothing more than class definitions, so yes, you need parameters to represent instances of them. The issue is not just that they are not instantiated, but that there are no properties for them at all.

Your idea to instantiate a copy of the outer class when you need one of the other classes doesn't make sense. And the only reason the compiler is requiring you to do that is you used the keyword `inner` in those class definitions. Since they have no shared references with Dataset, they do not need to be `inner`.

The meaning of `inner` is that the class can only exist within the context of an outer class. The benefit of an `inner` class is that it can directly reference properties of the outer class and you always know that any instance of the inner class is intrinsically linked to a specific instance of the outer class. You don't need any of these inner class features for a simple hierarchy like this.

You need something like this:

```
data class Table1 (var colA: String = "", 
                   var colB: String = "")

data class Table2 (var colX: String = "")

data class DataSet (var table1: Table1? = null,
                    var table2: Table2? = null)
```

Since your tables are optional, they must be nullable, and a null value represents that it is blank.

Using `data` in the class definition makes Kotlin generate `toString`, `hashcode` and `equals` for you.

Your example XML shows multiple Table1's in your Dataset, so you might need to change the parameters of DataSet to collections to be able to hold multiple tables of each type:

```
data class DataSet (val table1s: MutableList<Table1> = mutableListOf(),
                    val table2s: MutableList<Table2> = mutableListOf())
```

**Edit:** 
If you actually need these to be inner classes, you must have properties for instances of the inner classes. And you must always instantiate them in the context of the instance that will "own" it.

```
// This works because the table was instantiated from the dataset that will reference it.
val dataset = DataSet()
dataset.table1 = dataset.Table1() 

// This doesn't work because you can't assign the new DataSet's table to some 
// other DataSet's property.
val dataset = DataSet()
dataset.table1 = DataSet().Table1()
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, it's very helpful

_you always know that any instance of the inner class is intrinsically linked to a specific instance of the outer class_

that is the idea, I didn'y include the dataset specific properties because I thought they would obscure the view

I want to use the Dataset instance to have Dataset specific ContentProvider in Android, rather than multiple table specific ContentProviders

so assuming I keep the inner class I need to add the nullable properties representing  the inner classes in Dataset, correct? and then make them data classes

Comment: See edit for info about your problem with inner classes.

Comment: dataset.table1 = dataset.Table1() - this is exactly what I was missing, thanks a lot